# React input - cursor jump to the end

Tags: reactjs, formatting, format

I'm using this package `react-phone-number-input`

***Context***

I've this phone number field

```
<InputPhone
        {...input}
        value={input.value || ''}
        placeholder={intl.formatMessage(
          placeholder ? messages[placeholder] : messages.placeholder,
        )}
        style={{
          borderColor: meta && meta.touched && meta.error && 'red',
        }}
        tabIndex={index}
        size={size}
      />
```

This is inside a functional component, I cannot use another textInput because we use this little component in multiple forms plus it has special function inside it, like the style and the placeholder.

***Problem***

The problem is linked to this package `react-phone-number-input`: the caret jump to the end if i try to edit a number in the firsts two portions.

Someoneknow how can i fix it since the function SmartCaret of `react-phone-number-input` was disabled ?

Comment: Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem in a sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/catamphetamine/react-phone-number-input/issues/223) - sounds like your problem.

You could try out the [Smart Caret](http://catamphetamine.github.io/react-phone-number-input/) feature - the last item on the docs page. Keep in mind it might have limitations on some Android devices.

```
import SmartInput from 'react-phone-number-input/smart-input'

<PhoneInput
    inputComponent={ SmartInput }
    placeholder="Enter phone number"
    value={ this.state.value }
    onChange={ value => this.setState({ value }) }/>
```

Hope it helps!

---

If this doesn't work, a minimal, reproducible example would be helpful, like Dupocas suggested.